# Using a US state name or lat/long as the location parameter - HERE-API

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to create a list of all weather alerts in each US state.

I was wondering if there was any type of support from the Report API to get state specific weather data? I'd like to just supply a string like "Pennsylvania" as the only location parameter value but from my own testing/reading the docs it looks like this isn't supported.

Is there any other method to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Weather by state will not be accurate enough in many cases like Texas and California. County or Zip Code might be better.

Answer (score 0):

The below query gives the weather details in Pennsylvania. You can also try various options available by referring to Here Weather API documentation in  https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/auto_weather/weather-observation. Hope this helps!

```
https://weather.cit.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=observation&name=Pennsylvania&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```